# "Input not supported" on windows 10 but working on bios

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have 2 displays , one is 1920x1080 and the other one is 1240x1024 ( If I remember correctly ,definitely 4:3 though ) .

I use a vga to hdmi converter . My big monitor is displaying perfectly fine , when I try to swap the cables ( disconnect the big monitor and connect the small one ) I get the input not supported message floating, I also dropped the resolution to 800x600 before doing the whole procedure .  During boot the display works perfectly fine .So I assume there is no problem with the converter or the gpu . My graphics card is NVDIA GTX 1050ti and I use windows 10 . The small display is acer AL1715 (sorry for the information overload , but I'm fairly new and don't know what's useful info and what's not )

I am going to purchase a second converter , so I was wondering if there is a possibility something might be faulty or that the display is not supported by windows.

Edit : I also tried to use a vga to dvi-d adapter but apparently that's a bad idea. Windows doesn't recognize it on the device manager -> Monitors

Comment: VGA to HDMI can be tricky since you're changing the video from analog to digital.  Generally, a passive adapter causes issues or just doesn't work.  Since you're going from a digital signal on the card to an analog monitor, you will need an active adapter for the 1280x1024 monitor.

Comment: I'm using this one LANBERG AD-0016-BK HDMI-A(M) - VGA(F) ADAPTER

Comment: Can't tell if it's active or not.  Also, you can't convert DVI-D to VGA without an active converter, if you have DVI-I, that would work with a simple cable. (http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/221/~/difference-between-dvi-i-and-dvi-d)   Your best bet is to find an active adapter either DVI-D to VGA or HDMI to VGA.